# Setting Date range picker variables OnClose

Tags: jquery, daterangepicker

I'm trying to get the StartDate and EndDate variables of the date range picker when the OnClose function is called, however I am having difficulties.

I replaced

```
onClose: function(){},
```

with

```
onClose: alertdata,
```

However that already breaks the daterange picker and I cannot pick dates anymore.
According to the [documentation](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/date_range_picker_using_jquery_ui_16_and_jquery_ui_css_framework/), there already are variables set **dateStart** and **dateEnd**, so what I was going to do is this:

```
  function alertData() {
      $("#DivDateStart").html(dateStart); //update div for debugging
      $("#DivDateEnd").html(dateEnd); //update div for debugging
  }
```

And then just use those variables in a POST method to send all that to a PHP file. [Here is what I have now](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/datepicker/), I would be grateful if someone let me know where I made a mistake in getting the data, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try accessing each datepicker individually to get the selected dates like so:

```
onClose:function(){
    var startDate = $('#startDatePickerID').datepicker("getDate");
    var endDate = $('#endDatePickerID').datepicker("getDate");            
}
```

Here is a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/Rex3q/1/

**Update (based on comments)**

You can retrieve the start and end dates by modifying the source of the `daterangepicker.jQuery.js` file.

Replace the `hideRP` function with the function below:

```
function hideRP() {
    if (rp.data('state') == 'open') {
        rp.data('state', 'closed');
        rp.fadeOut(300);

        var startDate = rp.find('.range-start').datepicker('getDate');
        var endDate = rp.find('.range-end').datepicker('getDate');

        options.onClose(startDate, endDate);
    }
}
```

This will retrieve the start and end date from the individual datepickers and pass them to the `onClose` function.

Then when you initialise the `daterangepicker`, specify the `onClose` function like below:

```
$('#rangePickerID').daterangepicker(
{
    arrows: true,
    onClose: function (startDate, endDate) {
        alert(startDate);
        alert(endDate);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot jdavies! This looks extremely cool however I made a huge mistake as I am using daterangepicker, not datepicker. However, when inserting your code into the onClose function, the daterange picker is no longer broken- which means I might be able to use something from your code maybe?

Comment: Which date range picker are you using?

Comment: I am using date range picker form filamentgroup: http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/date_range_picker_using_jquery_ui_16_and_jquery_ui_css_framework/     :)

Comment: It doesn't seem to offer any way to retrieve the selected date(s), other than retrieving the value from the form element: `$('#id').val()`.

Comment: Wow jdavies, that is unbelievable! Thanks so much for reading through the comments and writing all this code, it means so much to me :))))! I am still unable to use the `startDate` and `endDate` variables in $("#DivDateStart").html(startDate);, but I hope I will get there soon :))) Thanks again :))

Comment: No problem, glad to help. The reason why you cannot write the dates out to html is because they are [Date](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp) objects and need to be converted to a suitable string representation like so: `$("#DivDateStart").html(startDate.toString())`.